# How to predict StackOverFlow?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

Imagine that you traverse a tree (not necessary binary, binary search or balanced one) in order to check if the given tree contains a particular item.

The tree is presented by a number of nodes with the following structure:

```
public class TreeNode<V> {
   private V value;
   private Collection<TreeNode<V>> children;
}
```

So, you traverse the given tree in recursive way.

What will be an approximate size of the tree (number of nested children) when StackOverFlow exception is thrown?

How to predict StackOverFlow in this case?

Comment: "What will be an approximate size of the tree (number of nested children) when StackOverFlow exception is thrown?" depends on the size of your stack.

Comment: "What will be an approximate size of the tree" the *size* isn't especially relevant, it's the depth of the recursion which matters.

Comment: Make the tree reasonably balanced and you won't get a stack overflow.  You would only get an error if you didn't balance the tree and it degraded into a list.

Comment: You cannot predict it even if you know the size of the tree. You do it by trial and error and set your stack size -Xss using the command.

Comment: A balanced tree with a depth of 100 would need to have 2^100 element or more memory than all the computers in the world. a depth of 300 is more than the number of atoms in the observable universe. Most JVMs can handle thousands of stack depth by default.

Comment: Why can’t I do it if I can figure out size of thread’s stack and I know the size of reference to the objects?

Comment: The depth the stack will go to isn't something you can calculate and it's not even stable from one run to the next or repeatable in the same JVM even for trivial examples. However you can calculate that the stack size will always be larger than you could possibly have for a balanced tree. i.e. the value doesn't matter as you won't get close.

Comment: The OP specifically said that the tree is not necessarily balanced. The problem with all these suggestions to "make sure your tree is balanced" is that it's not always possible to do so. Sure, you can ensure that search trees are balanced. But try doing that with a hierarchy that is highly skewed, like a parse tree. Or a family tree. Or a large pairing heap implemented as a left-child, right-sibling binary tree. Balanced trees are a special case that, in my experience, don't occur nearly as often in the real world as do unbalanced trees.